# How do you re-route multiple Express.js paths and return a single result?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have several .get requests that I normally call, like this:
notesController

```
controller.get('/customers/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const customers = await Customer.find();
    res.status(200).send(customers);
  });

controller.get('/documents/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const orders = await Order.find();
    res.status(200).send(orders);
  });
```

In certain circumstances, I'd like to be able to call both at once, like this:

```
controller.get('/version/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const ver = await Version.findById(req.headers.sub);
  if (req.headers.dbversion === ver.dbversion) {
     res.status(200).send({ versionMatch: true });
   } else {
     req.url = '/customers/';
     const custData = await controller.handle(req, res, next);
     req.url = '/orders/';
     const orders = await controller.handle(req, res, next);
     res.status(200).send({ customers: custData, docs: invoices });
     }
   });
```

But this doesn't work. Adding a console message in my .get('/customers') function, I can see that it is being called, but isn't returning any data. My desired result is that I make one API call, and if the conditions are met, it returns both sets of data at once. How do I best achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with express. Your best bet is make the functions that handle the request standalone functions, and when your conditions are met call them to get both data sets.

```
controller.get('/customers/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const customers = findCustomers(args);
    if (condition is met) {
      const orders = findOrders();
    }
    res.status(200).send({ customers, orders });
  });

controller.get('/documents/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const orders = findOrders(args);
    res.status(200).send(orders);
  });

function findCustomers(args) {
  const customers = await Customer.find();
  return customers;
}
function findOrders(args) {
  const orders = await Order.find();
  return orders
}
```